# Describe $S=\{x\mid x\in\mathbb Z\}$ as open, closed, or neither, and find $S^o$, $(S^c)^o$, and $(S^o)^c$

Tags: real-analysis

> Describe $S=\{x\mid x\in\mathbb Z\}$ as open, closed, or neither, and find 
>   $S^o$, 
>   $(S^c)^o$, and
>   $(S^o)^c$

**(a) Open?**

the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of any integer is not contained in the set $S$ (as $\epsilon$ can be a fraction). Therefore $S$ is not open.

---

**(b) Closed?**

As $S^c$ is open, $S$ is closed.

---

**(c)$S^o$?**

There is no interior point whose $\epsilon$-neighborhood is contained. Therefore $S^o = \varnothing $

---

**(d)$(S^c)^o$?**

### $$(S^c)^o = \big(\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb Z}(k, k+1)\big)^o=\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb Z}(k, k+1)=\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Z $$

**(e)$(S^o)^c$?**

### $$(S^o)^c =\mathbb R $$

Am I going in the right direction? Is there a more efficient way to explain?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Looks good for me

Comment: Do you mean "Describe $S$ as open, closed or neither _as a subset of_ $\Bbb R$ (with the standard topology / metric)?" Because on its own, a set is never open or closed; it doesn't even make sense to ask.

Comment: I assumed S as a subset of R as the section of the book "the real line" introduce the topic that the universal set is R

Comment: @gegu:  If you are asking about $S$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, the real line (to supply a topology), then this should be expressed in the body of your Question.  However it seems peculiar to define $S$ in this way since it amounts to $S=\mathbb{Z}$.